# "C compiler not found" compiling NDK code Mac

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, x264, ndk-build, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to compile ffmpeg wrapper [GitHub link](https://github.com/rockcarry/fanplayer) but getting issues in configuring it. In build_ffmpeg_for_android.sh file I have following lines at start and these are not working so far.

```
PREFIX_DIR=$PWD/ffmpeg-android-sdk
SYSROOT=$NDK_HOME/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
CROSS_COMPILE=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi- 
4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
EXTRA_CFLAGS="-I$PREFIX_DIR/include -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Os -ffast-math -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=softfp"
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-L$PREFIX_DIR/lib"

#++ build x264 ++#
if true; then
if [ ! -d x264 ]; then
   git clone -b stable git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
fi
cd x264
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX_DIR \
--enable-strip \
--enable-static \
--enable-pic \
--disable-cli \
--disable-opencl \
--disable-avs \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--cross-prefix=$CROSS_COMPILE \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT
```

Error that I am unable to get rid of is "C compiler not found". I have verified all paths mentioned at top of file and added missing paths to env too but still same issue. I have tried it in ubuntu too and facing same issue there. Many users faced similar issues but those fixes are not seems to be working for me. Any pointers will be helpful.

FYI: I have not worked on NDK much therefore there might be something silly that i have missed.

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: Yes gcc is installed properly.

Comment: Building FFmpeg with NDK r19 is quite straightforward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228027/632035

Comment: Problem was with NDK version I have to research a lot to find exact version for which it compiles successfully. As GCC support was depreciated it was causing issue so had to try with old versions of NDK to make it work.